# How do I import an existing SQLite3 database into Room?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

Okay so I used SQLite3 on desktop to create a database of certain information that need only be read. The app I am making does not need to insert or delete information from this table.

I've done a fair bit of Googling on the Room database layer and all the documentation entails creating a fresh database in Room while your app is built -- something I do not want, since I already have one.

How would I go about having Room read an already-existing database? My database is currently stored in `/app/src/main/assets/splitbilldatabase.db`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Room 2.2.0 or greater, you can configure the database builder to start by loading the DB from the assets folder.

```
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, "splitbilldatabase.db")
    .createFromAsset("splitbilldatabase.db")
    .build()
```

more info: 
- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is create everything for the Room schema ready for the import (@Database, @Entity's for the tables etc), which must **exactly match** the schema of the database to be imported.

The external database file should be copied (as you have) to the assets folder.

You can then basically copy the file before any attempt to open the Room database e.g. in the `RoomDatabase` **`init`** method, but **only if the file/database doesn't already exist**.

The following is a working (but not extensively tested) example :-

```
@Database(entities = {MyTable.class,
        MyOthertable.class,
        MyMappingTable.class},version = 1,
        exportSchema = false)

public abstract class  MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static final String DBNAME = "splitbilldatabase.db";


    public static final String TB_MYTABLE = "mytable";
    public static final String TB_MYOTHERTABLE = "myothertable";
    public static final String TB_MYMAPPINGTABLE = "mymappingtable";

    public static final String COL_MYTABLE_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_MYTABLE_NAME = "_name";
    public static final String COL_MYTABLE_DESCRIPTION = "_description";

    public static final String COL_MYOTHERTABLE_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_MYOTHERTABLE_OTHERDETAILS = "_otherdetails";

    public static  final String COL_MYMAPPINGTABLE_MYTABLEREFERENCE = "_mytable_reference";
    public static final String COL_MYMAPPINGTABLE_MYOTEHERTABLEREFERENCE = "_myothertable_reference";

    public abstract MyTableDao myTableDao();
    public abstract MyOtherTableDao myOtherTableDao();
    public abstract MyMappingTableDao myMappingTableDao();

    public MyDatabase() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(@NonNull DatabaseConfiguration configuration) {
        importExistingDatabase(configuration.context, true); //<<<<<<<<<< Invokes the Import of the Exisiting Database.
        super.init(configuration);
    }

    private void importExistingDatabase(Context context, boolean throw_exception) {
        int buffer_size = 32768;
        File dbpath = context.getDatabasePath(DBNAME);
        if (dbpath.exists()) {
            return; // Database already exists
        }
        // Just in case make the directories
        File dirs = new File(dbpath.getParent());
        dirs.mkdirs();
        int stage = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
        long total_bytes_read = 0;
        long total_bytes_written = 0;
        int bytes_read = 0;
        try {  
            InputStream assetdb = context.getAssets().open(DBNAME);
            stage++;
            dbpath.createNewFile();
            stage++;
            OutputStream realdb = new FileOutputStream(dbpath);
            stage++;
            while((bytes_read = assetdb.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                total_bytes_read = total_bytes_read + bytes_read;
                realdb.write(buffer,0,bytes_read);
                total_bytes_written = total_bytes_written + bytes_read;
            }
            stage++;
            realdb.flush();
            stage++;
            assetdb.close();
            stage++;
            realdb.close();
            stage++;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String failed_at = "";
            switch  (stage) {
                case 0:
                    failed_at = "Opening Asset " + DBNAME;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    failed_at = "Creating Output Database " + dbpath.getAbsolutePath();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    failed_at = "Genreating Database OutputStream " + dbpath.getAbsolutePath();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    failed_at = "Copying Data from Asset Database to Output Database. " +
                            " Bytes read=" + String.valueOf(total_bytes_read) +
                            " Bytes written=" + String.valueOf(total_bytes_written);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    failed_at = "Flushing Written Data (" +
                            String.valueOf(total_bytes_written) +
                            " bytes written)";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    failed_at = "Closing Asset Database File.";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    failed_at = "Closing Created Database File.";
            }
            String msg = "An error was encountered copying the Database " +
                    "from the asset file to New Database. " +
                    "The error was encountered whilst :-\n\t" + failed_at;
            Log.e("IMPORTDATABASE",msg);
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (throw_exception) {
                throw new RuntimeException(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Note the assumption is that the file names are the same.

Comment: So I don't need to add anything extra to the database for Android to like it?

Comment: @SikuM I don't believe so. The extra tables (1 for room and android_metadata that stores the locale will be created by the underlying code)