# How to query preloaded database file with Android Room?

Tags: android, database, android-room

I'm trying to create an Android app where I work on the DB separately (trying to use DB Browser for SQLite). Then I'll paste the db file into my project and load the data using Room. However, I'm having troubes picking up any results as it looks like my query returns nothing.

My table in DB Browser is called "Users" with "ID", "FirstName" and "LastName" as columns. I saved this as "testDB.db". I then put this file into a created directory called "assets" in Android Studio.

Here are my classes to try to make this simple test code work:

```
User class:
@Entity(tableName = "Users")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey var ID: Int,
    @ColumnInfo (name = "FirstName") val firstName: String,
    @ColumnInfo (name = "LastName") val lastName: String) {
}

UserDao class:
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Users")
    fun loadAllUsers(): Array<User>
}

UserDatabase class:
@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 2, exportSchema = false)
abstract class UserDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao

    companion object {
        // Singleton prevents multiple instances of database opening at the
        // same time.
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: UserDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context, scope: CoroutineScope): UserDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    UserDatabase::class.java,
                    "testDB"
                )
                    .createFromAsset("testDB.db") //relative to assets folder
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
}

Main Activity:
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        val job = Job()
        val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)

        var database = UserDatabase.getDatabase(this, scope)

        scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

                val users = database.userDao().loadAllUsers()

                Log.i("test", "First user ${users[0]}") //Crash here since users not picked up


        }
```

So it seems when I try to use my query and try to select everything from USERS, then no users are picked up and the app tries to crash when I try to scope out my results. What I've tried to do is match my entities as close to my test database file as possible, but it's still not working.

Is there some way to associate an existing database table with your @Entity classes so that you can select and display all data from the database?

EDIT:
Here's the error

```
2020-07-27 21:01:13.408 4679-4705/martin.ngyn.dev.testdatabase E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: martin.ngyn.dev.testdatabase, PID: 4679
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
        at martin.ngyn.dev.testdatabase.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:28)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740)
```

So pretty much the query isn't returning anything.

Comment: As you mentioned about app crashing, could you please add crash report along with asked question?

Comment: I've edited the main post. The error is that the query isn't returning anything.

Comment: You cant just drag and drop a sqlite database into an android project. Room does some magic on its own. Check out this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51110520/how-do-i-import-an-existing-sqlite3-database-into-room

Comment: Just pull out the copied db from app internal directory and cross-check the  asset db that you have, whether copied db contains any records or not, if it contains records then just double check that both db has similar data or not.

Comment: For debugging, disable `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` so that you will get an error if your prepopulated database is not compatible with your Room schema.  Are you confident the version number of your prepopulated database is 2?